# How do I get the current Activiti ProcessInstance in SpringBean?

Tags: spring, process, workflow, bpmn, activiti

I am trying to get a workflow working using Activiti 5.5 using a Spring managed process engine and I'm having some trouble.

I have a ServiceTask in my workflow that resolves to a Spring Managed bean. It looks like this:

```
<serviceTask id="springTask1" name="BeanTest" activiti:delegateExpression="${taskBean}"></serviceTask>
```

I am not starting the process via code, the process is either started via the activti-rest api or a form. How can I get the context in which this task is executing from inside the bean, so that I might be able to add a process variable that could be referenced in a later task, such as an email.  I tried looking at the spring examples that come with Activiti 5.5 and I do not see how my example is any different from the examples.  I am implementing the JavaDelegate interface the same wat the spring example shows.

Here is my code:

```
public class GetBeanTest implements JavaDelegate {

private ContactService contactService;

public GetBeanTest() {
    super();
}

public String getContactName(String contactName) throws Exception {
    String retVal= "unknown";
    if(contactService == null){
        System.out.println("Bean was null!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Bean is valid!");
        List<Contact> contacts= contactService.getContacts();
        System.out.println("There are " + contacts.size() +" in the contact list.");
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            if(contact.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(contactName)){
                System.out.println("Found the contact! " + contactName );
                retVal= contact.getEmail();
            }
        }
    }
    return retVal;

}

public void setContactService(ContactService contactService) {
    this.contactService = contactService;
}

@Override
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++ in execute ++++++++++++++++");
    System.out.println("Event Name: " + execution.getEventName());
    System.out.println("ID: " + execution.getId());
    System.out.println("Process Instance ID: " + execution.getProcessInstanceId());
    Set<String> varNames= execution.getVariableNames();
    for (String string : varNames) {
        System.out.println("Varible Named " + string + " exists");
        if(string.equalsIgnoreCase("contactName")){
            String contactName= (String) execution.getVariable(string);
            getContactName(contactName);
        }else{
            System.out.println("unable to find contact name.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the spring config (boring parts left out for brevity):

```
<bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
  </bean>

<!--Dao Beans -->
<bean id="contactDao" class="org.psc.database.dao.jpa.ContactDaoImpl"/>

<!--  Service Beans -->

  <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
  <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
  <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />
  <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />
  <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />
  <bean id="identityService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getIdentityService" />

<bean id="contactService" class="org.psc.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl">
    <property name="contactDao" ref="contactDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="contact" class="org.psc.bpmn.tasks.Contact"/>
<bean id="taskBean" class="org.psc.bpmn.examples.GetBeanTest">
        <property name="contactService" ref="contactService"/>
</bean>
```

When I run the worflow, I get an error:

> 06090000 Wrapped Exception (with status template): Delegate expression ${taskBean} did not resolve to an implementation of interface org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.delegate.ActivityBehavior nor interface org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate

Any/All replies appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring beans in service tasks this way also:

1. You should make a spring managed bean (implements JavaDelegate not needed)
2. use this configuration in ServiceTask: activiti:expression="${taskBean.someMethod()}"

I always use this configuration in spring environment. Hope it helps!

Levi

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the `ProcessEngine`
2. Get the task service
3. Create a query to find the process instance, `taskService.createTaskQuery()`
4. Finally, `task.getProcessInstanceId()`